# How to use (.NET and NHibernate - CreateSQLQuery) (disuse of "Foreach")

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, foreach

I used under code for long time, But I think it is inefficient because it should be executed several times.

So, I want to disuse of "Foreach" and same perfomance.

```
public void SaveProgramListinsertWithCart(List<ProductDto> insertList)
{
      foreach (ProductDto insertItem in insertList)
      {
             Session.CreateSQLQuery(@"insert into Cart (ProdCode, Qty,  CustId)
                                      values (:prodCode, :qty, :custid)")                
             .SetParameter("prodCode", insertItem.ProdCode, NHibernateUtil.String)
             .SetParameter("qty", insertItem.Qty, NHibernateUtil.Int32)
             .SetParameter("custid", insertItem.CustId, NHibernateUtil.String)
             .List();
      }                    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To execute an insert/update with `CreateSQLQuery`, you have to call the `ExecuteUpdate` method, for sample:

```
foreach (ProductDto insertItem in insertList)
{
    var query = Session.CreateSQLQuery(@"insert into Cart (ProdCode, Qty,  CustId)
                                        values (:prodCode, :qty, :custid)")                
                        .SetParameter("prodCode", insertItem.ProdCode, NHibernateUtil.String)
                        .SetParameter("qty", insertItem.Qty, NHibernateUtil.Int32)
                        .SetParameter("custid", insertItem.CustId, NHibernateUtil.String);

    int result = query.ExecuteUpdate();
}
```

On the other hand, I don't think use a SQL to execute an insert is the best approach you can do with and ORM tool like NHibernate. The best approach in my opinion if to post the mapped object into `ISession` instance, for sample:

```
foreach (ProductDto insertItem in insertList)
{
    var product = new Product();
    product.ProdCode = insertItem.ProdCode;
    product.CustId = insertItem.CustId;
    product.Qty = insertItem.Qty;

    Session.Save(product);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But your code still used "FOREACH".

Comment: So, I think that it should be connected DB several times.  I know IO connection has an effect on program perfomance. For this reason, I really want remove "FOREACH".

Comment: Well, you need to post each entry for each item on the list right? You need this loop. You can configure Batch Size if you want, but it is a question for another thread :)

Comment: It's very nice of you. To remove loop, I will send List<T> to SP...! In this way, I expect to reduce IO connection.  But, I don't know how to do it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think there is no way to do it. You could send an varchar to a SP and split inside that but I'm not sure if it is the best approach!